# How to store dropdownlist selected value into an arraylist session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I'm trying to store the selected value in `dropdownlist` into an `ArrayList` `Session`. Currently I'm using the following method to store the selected value into the `Session`.

```
    DropDownList ddlSize = item.FindControl("ddlSize") as DropDownList;
    DropDownList ddlCrust = item.FindControl("ddlCrust") as DropDownList;

    ArrayList prodSize = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList prodCrust = new ArrayList();

    prodSize = (ArrayList)Session["prodSize"];
    prodCrust = (ArrayList)Session["prodCrust"];

    prodSize.Add(ddlSize.SelectedValue).ToString();
    prodCrust.Add(ddlCrust.SelectedValue).ToString();
```

I ended up getting error saying `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Answer (score 1):

Either of the last two lines may produce your error because any of `ddlSize`, `ddlCrust`, `prodSize`, `prodCrust`, or `.SelectedValue`s is `null`. Try to rewrite this way.

```
DropDownList ddlSize = item.FindControl("ddlSize") as DropDownList;
DropDownList ddlCrust = item.FindControl("ddlCrust") as DropDownList;

//ArrayList prodSize = new ArrayList(); /redundant
//ArrayList prodCrust = new ArrayList();

var prodSize = Session["prodSize"] as ArrayList;
var prodCrust = Session["prodCrust"] as ArrayList;

if(prodSize != null && ddlSize != null && ddlSize.SelectedValue != null)
    prodSize.Add(ddlSize.SelectedValue); // makes no sense .ToString();
if(prodCrust != null && ddlCrust != null && ddlCrust.SelectedValue != null)
    prodCrust.Add(ddlCrust.SelectedValue); // see above .ToString();
```

Comment: Can I ask you on how to retrieve the value that I had save in the ArrayList Session?

Comment: By index in `ArrayList`

Comment: sorry to ask but what do you mean by using index in `ArrayList`?

Comment: currently im using this method:            `var prodSize = Session["prodSize"] as ArrayList;
            
            foreach (var item in prodSize)
            {
                Label lblSize = e.Item.FindControl("lblSize") as Label;

                lblSize.Text = prodSize.ToString();
            }`

Comment: `var someVal = prodSize[0];`

Comment: Just realise I still retrieve null value